# Splitting integrals in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I know that for $f \in L^1$, and $\mu(S) > 0$, we have $$\int_X f \, d\mu = \int_{X \setminus S} f \,  d\mu + \int_{S} f \, d\mu.$$ Is the same true in $L^p$? Or do we now get an inequality? Namely, does

$$\left(\int_X f^p \, d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \left(\int_{X \setminus S} f^p \, d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\left(\int_S f^p \, d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}?$$

I'm trying to prove $L^p$ is separable by showing the collection$$ S:= \{\sum_{i=1}^nr\chi_{(a_i,b_i)}\}_{(a_i,b_i,r) \in \mathbb{Q}^3}$$ is dense in $L^p$, which leads me to the estimate, given $\chi_E$, $E$ measurable, and a member of $S$ with $r=1$, then $$\left(\int_X |\chi_E - \chi_{(a,b)}| \, d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \left(\int_{E \setminus (a,b)} (1) \right)^\frac{1}{p} + \left(\int_{(a,b) \setminus E} (1) \right)^\frac{1}{p}  $$ since $|\chi_E - \chi_{(a,b)}|$ is $0$ except on $(a,b) \setminus E \cup E \setminus (a,b)$. Also, am I correct in saying that if I can get the difference of the coefficients to add up to less than $1$ and the difference in the measure of the sets for the simple function to add up to less than $\epsilon^p$ then I've proven density?

Comment: I think your definitions for L^p spaces are slightly incorrect, it should be $|f|$ instead of just $f$ (at least in all the books I've seen so far).

Comment: @Olorun Sorry. $f$ is unsigned and positive here.

Comment: Is $\sqrt{\int_0^31^2dx}=\sqrt{\int_0^11^2dx}+\sqrt{\int_1^31^2dx}$ or is $\sqrt3=1+\sqrt2\,$?

Comment: @zoli Is the inequality $\leq$ true then?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not true. Generally
$$
\left(\int_X f^p \, d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \left(\int_{X \setminus S} f^p \, d\mu+ \int_{S} f^p \, d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\ne\left(\int_{X \setminus S} f^p \, d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\left(\int_S f^p \, d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
By Minkowski inequality
$$
\left(\int_X |\chi_E - \chi_{(a,b)}| \, d\mu \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leqslant \left(\int_{E \setminus (a,b)} (1) \right)^\frac{1}{p} + \left(\int_{(a,b) \setminus E} (1) \right)^\frac{1}{p}  
$$

Comment: Ah I see, it's a neat little trick to slide between characteristic functions and domains of integration :) I did exactly this in my most recent question.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503087/lp-mathbbr-separable